# Excel Text to Columns Formula

Tags: excel

I am given the left column and want the right column to give the number in the left column or the highest number in the left column if there are two numbers given:

[image: Before]

I am using this equation to calculate the right column, given the left.

```
=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-SEARCH("-",B2,SEARCH(" ",B2,1)+1))
```

This is what I want to display in the right column:

[image: After]

If anyone can help me fix that equation to display the number instead of value when there is only 1 number in the cell it would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your same formula as you solved the harder part of the problem which is parsing out the higher value.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),B2,VALUE(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-SEARCH("-",B2,SEARCH(" ",B2,1)+1))))`

Comment: Thank you!! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
=IFERROR(MID(B5,SEARCH("-",B5)+1,999),B5)
```

If you *also* want to return a value rather than a string, use this one, and format the cells as currency (as I think your left hand column already is)

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(MID(B2,SEARCH("-",B2)+1,999)),B2)
```